# Why is an Option<i32> not consumed when it is passed to a function?

Tags: rust, option-type, ownership

The `plus_one` function doesn't take a reference as an argument. Shouldn't the ownership of five be passed to `plus_one`? Why is `five` still usable?

```
fn plus_one(x: Option<i32>) -> Option<i32> {
    match x {
        None => None,
        Some(i) => Some(i + 1),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let five = Some(5);
    let six = plus_one(five);
    println!("{}", five.unwrap());
    println!("{}", six.unwrap());
    let none = plus_one(None);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`i32` is `Copy`. An [`Option` of something that is `Copy` is also `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Copy):

```
impl<T> Copy for Option<T>
where
    T: Copy,
```

Thus, passing `five` to `plus_one` copies instead of moves.

Comment: `Option<T>` is `Copy` if and only if `T` is `Copy`.